# Append child block at the specific place of parent block using Notion API

Tags: notion-api

I have parent page where multiple child pages are coming like this:

- child page 3
- child page 2
- child page 1

Now I want to add **child page 4** at the beginning.
Currently I could only add to the end of the page [using this endpoint](https://developers.notion.com/reference/patch-block-children) but this is not what I want.

Is there a way to implement it? More generally, can I add **child page 2.5** between 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on Notion's Slack and looks like it is not possible with current API.
Feel free to update in future if it changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete children's from page, modify list in code and create once again.
With Python api I did something like this to add cover at the beginning:

```
list = client.blocks.children.list(page_id)
for block in list['results']:
    client.blocks.delete(block['id'])
    children = []
    children.append({'image': {'external': {'url': 'cover_url'}}})
    children.extend(list['results'])
    client.blocks.children.append(block_id=page_id, children=children)
```